# "refused to connect" with https and let-encyrpt

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https, lets-encrypt

I've successfully created the SSL certificate and the key for my website via letsencrypt.org . I uploaded them in a folder on the server. I get no errors when I start the server.

But when I try to load the website in the browser using https://, I get the "refused to connect" error.

Here is the code I am using to create the https server:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const fs =  require('fs');
const http=  require('http');
const https=  require('https');
const path = require('path');

const PRIVATEKEY_PATH = path.join(__dirname, '../ssl/server.key');
const CERTIFICATE_PATH = path.join(__dirname, '../ssl/server.crt');

var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync(PRIVATEKEY_PATH, 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync(CERTIFICATE_PATH, 'utf8');
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};

// Constants
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

const CLIENT_BUILD_PATH = path.join(__dirname, '../../300meter.ch/build');

// App
const app = express();

// Static files
app.use(express.static(CLIENT_BUILD_PATH));

//ssh

var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

// All remaining requests return the React app, so it can handle routing.
app.get('*', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.join(CLIENT_BUILD_PATH, 'index.html'));
});

httpServer.listen(PORT, HOST);
httpsServer.listen(8443, HOST);
```

If somebody could help me, that would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: In my experience, the `https` port is usually set to 443. I also used `letsencrypt` for my express app but I had set up an nginx reverse proxy which redirected http/https requests to my application listening on port 3000. Perhaps that is something you can try too

Answer (score 0):

When you specify https://example.com, the client connects to port 443. You do not have your SSL server running on port 443. Your server is running on port 8443.

You will need to specify https://example.com:8443/ in the URL.

Comment: thank you. It worked now but I have some problems with the certificate. The Padlock does not appear and the browser says that the site is not safe.

Comment: In Chrome, Edge, etc. you can press F12 to enable the debugger. Then press CTRL-F5 to reload the page. Do you see any warning in the debugger? Fix those. This is usually caused by your HTML content referencing other objects (CSS, JS, ...) via HTTP links instead of HTTPS.